# Google ReCaptcha V3 integration with ASP.NET Web Application (.net Framework)

Tags: asp.net, web, web-applications, recaptcha

Last year, I implemented Google reCAPTCHA v3 in my application using the code explained in this [GitHub repository](https://github.com/WestleyBennett/reCAPTCHAv3/tree/main).

Starting last week, we've been receiving multiple emails from users reporting issues with submitting their requests. Upon investigation, I observed that the return score from Google is consistently 0.3.

In some cases, users have been able to resolve the issue by clicking the Submit button multiple times, while in others, users remain stuck on the page.

Upon checking our Google reCAPTCHA dashboard, I came across the following message: "We detected that your site is not verifying reCAPTCHA tokens. Please see our developer site for more information." I'm uncertain if there's any connection between this message and the low score issue we're experiencing.
Regrettably, I couldn't find a definitive solution to this problem on the Google reCAPTCHA site or elsewhere on the internet.

Furthermore, most of the available code samples online are geared towards .NET Core, MVC, and Angular, with limited resources for ASP.NET web applications.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance or support in resolving this issue.

P.S.: Our application is hosted on Azure (Azure App Service).